# Using the MediaCapture API, StartRecordToStorageFileAsync fails to return and does not raise an error

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, video-capture

I'm trying to use this MediaCapture API sample:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

but when I press Start Record to record to a file, this line never returns:

```
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, m_recordStorageFile);
```

And no error is thrown.  This computer is a Cyberpower PC.  The sample DOES work on my other windows 10 computer (a mac mini) though.  I thought maybe it was a codec issue but can't find any information on installing codecs so maybe that is not it--not sure.  Thank you for any help or information.

Additional Info:  Creating a profile like this works:

```
MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = null;
recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
```

But calling CreateMp4 instead of CreateWmv does not work.

Comment: How are you creating the recordProfile in this scenario? What computer does this not work on?

Comment: @Mike, My question is edited to include your requested info.  Since I asked this, I did see that it will work calling CreateWmv, just not CreateMp4, please see the question above.

Comment: Does it work if you try the new Windows 10 sample? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit

Comment: @Mike, you may be on to something, but that sample won't open in community visual studio 2015.  Not sure what version of visual studio works.  That sample might target .net 4.6 instead of 4.5.1 which may work better with windows 10.  Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, the sample targets Windows 10. My suspicion is that there's something wrong with that particular installation's encoders. If you can upgrade it to Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2015 you can develop universal apps.

Comment: @Mike, you were right.  After Updating to windows 10 the problem went away. How to mark as answer?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've posted my comment as a standalone answer, if you want to accept it as having solved your issue. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that there's something wrong with your particular installation's encoders. If you can upgrade to Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2015 you can develop universal apps. The same code should work without an issue.